# Convert my own DB.JSON file into working API URL to use in REACT REDUX project

Tags: json, api, react-redux

I want to convert my own db.json file into a working API URL to use in my practice react redux project. Can anyone suggest me open source free websites?

DB.JSON

```
{
  "navLinks": {
    "logo": {
      "url": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/10620143/pexels-photo-10620143.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"
    },
    "parentLinks": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "link": "Shop"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "link": "Learn",
        "subLinks": [
          { "id": 1, "link": "Process" },
          { "id": 2, "link": "About Us" },
          { "id": 3, "link": "Blog" },
          { "id": 4, "link": "News" },
          { "id": 5, "link": "Beyond The Bottle" }
        ]
      },
      { "id": 3, "link": "Sign Up" },
      { "id": 4, "link": "Login" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found the website which can convert your db.json file data into a url which you can use it your practice project.

**Checkout this link**
https://app.json-generator.com/

**Steps to follow:**

0. signup with your email id
1. copy your db.json data and paste into generate data section
2. click on generate data button, this will generate your data
3. click on get data and copy url e.g:https://api.json-generator.com/templates/cq7jZIauJXPO/data
4. go to the login dropdown and click on access token and generate token
5. copy the token and keep in your notepad
6. add ?access_token=PASTE_YOUR_GENERATED_TOKEN
7. https://api.json-generator.com/templates/cq7jZIauJXPO/data?access_token=PASTE_YOUR_GENERATED_TOKEN

Done.